# Unique pointer in base class prohibts instantiation with error "attempting to reference a deleted function"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I updated my C++ toolchain from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2017/2019.

Now I am experiencing a number of compile errors in the form:

```
<source>(13): error C2280: 'OfflineFixture::OfflineFixture(const OfflineFixture &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

<source>(8): note: compiler has generated 'OfflineFixture::OfflineFixture' here

<source>(8): note: 'OfflineFixture::OfflineFixture(const OfflineFixture &)': function was implicitly deleted because a data member invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)'
```

A unique pointer is a member of class that has no constructor and destructor.
In this case Visual Studio allows to instantiate an object this way:

```
OfflineFixture a{};  // works!
```

But using:

```
auto&& a = OfflineFixture{};
```

gives above compile error.

```
const auto& a = OfflineFixture{};
```

also gives above compile error.

Please have a look here:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/XtP40t

**My question is: Is my code wrong?**

The given examples compiles using:
gcc (9.1 and lower) 
clang
Visual Studio 2013

But it fails in:

- Visual Studio 2015
- Visual Studio 2017
- Visual Studio 2019

One way to fix this is to implement a default constructor in OfflineFixture.

**Minimal example:**

```
#include <memory>

struct OfflineFixture
{
    void x() const {} 
    int i;
    std::unique_ptr<int> m_calc;
};

int test() {

#if 1
    const auto&& a = OfflineFixture{};
#else
    OfflineFixture a{};
#endif
    a.x();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _Why_ do you need a reference to a temporary?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am pretty sure you can. The lifetime will be extended...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "The lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a const lvalue reference or to an rvalue reference (since C++11)"

Comment: The given code compiles just fine with MSVS 2017 (C++17 enabled).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think you are wrong. [Reference initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary).

Comment: @tkausl I do not. This is existing code that worked but broke with the Visual Studio Upgrade. I just want to know who is to blame :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make some preliminary points here.

In general, the statement:

```
const auto&& a = Foo{};
```

is perfectly legal in *C++*. Moreover, it is **not** true that it is undefined behavior.  In fact, this is a perfect example of [Reference Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) with lifetime extension of a temporary.

> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to a subobject thereof, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference [...].

It continues with some exceptions (I won't quote all of them), but the declaration of a new object is not part of those exceptions.

---

Regarding your class, it appears to be clear the problem is the `std::unique_ptr` member.

Here a minimal example:

```
#include <memory>

struct OfflineFixture {
  std::unique_ptr<int> m_calc;
};

void test() {
  const auto&& a = OfflineFixture{};  // <--- Error in msvc
}
```

Somehow, *MSVC* tries to create a copy of the object. Indeed, the error is about invoking the *copy constructor* (which is deleted because of `std::unique_ptr`).

Since no copies should be performed here, it appears to be a *msvc* bug.

Note: *gcc* and *clang* compile fine with that.

Answer (score 1):

I have added `constructor` and `move constructor` as shown in below code.

This resolves the issue.

```
struct OfflineFixture
{
    void x() const {} 
    int i;
    std::unique_ptr<int> m_calc;

    OfflineFixture(){}
    OfflineFixture(OfflineFixture &&){}

    //implicit
    OfflineFixture(const OfflineFixture&) = default;
    OfflineFixture& operator=(const OfflineFixture&) = default;
    ~OfflineFixture() = default;

 };
```

As, `const auto&& a = OfflineFixture{};` requires `constructor` and `move constructor`

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting to note that *MSVC* shows this erroneous behavior only if you do not provide a constructor or if you provide a default one:

```
struct OfflineFixture {
    OfflineFixture()=default;
    //...
};
```

The example can be fixed by providing a constructor with an empty block:

```
struct OfflineFixture {
    OfflineFixture(){}
    //...
};
```

which compiles just fine.